# How to make @RequestParam configurable through .properties file?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-mongodb

How we can make following configurable through .properties file?

```
@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false, defaultValue="0") Integer page,
@RequestParam(value = "size", required = false,defaultValue="8") Integer size,
```

How to make `defaultValue="0"` and `defaultValue="8"` configurable through .properties file in Spring MVC? Also how we can do it in  `@PageableDefault(size = 8, page = 0)` ?

Answer (score 11):

@RequestParam supports placeholders syntax like ${x.y}, check [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-placeholders).

1. Define required properties in a property file as application.properties        `request.defaultPageValue=0`
2. Load the property file in your servlet xml config.

   `<context:property-placeholder ignore-unresolvable="true" location="/WEB-INF/application.properties"/>`
3. Use the property in requestParam

   `@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false, defaultValue="${request.defaultPageValue}") Integer page,`

For setting default values in Pageable, same idea use placeHolder syntax to load integers, check related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27032433/set-default-page-size-for-jpa-pageable-object).

Comment: its perfectly working for me RequestParam, not tested Pageable, which one is not working for you ?

Comment: Not useful to me for following
public final int pageIndex = Integer.parseInt(Properties.getProperty("pagination.page.index")); public final int pageSize = Integer.parseInt(Properties.getProperty(".pagination.page.size")); @PageableDefault(size = pageIndex, page = pageSize ) Pageable pageable