# Spring Boot: Set defaultValue in RequestParam to a value in application.properties?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is there a way to set the defaultValue to a value from the application.properties file?

```
@ResponseBody
public void test(@RequestParam(name="testValue", defaultValue = <something from application.properties>))
```

Comment: See this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32587551/how-to-make-requestparam-configurable-through-properties-file

Answer (score 1):

Declare your `defaultValue` as a controller variable like this

```
@Value("${variable.name.in.app.properties}")
private String myDefaultValue;
```

Then, in your controller action, assign it like this

```
@ResponseBody
public void test(@RequestParam(name="testValue", defaultValue = myDefaultValue))
```

Comment: Can you not just `defaultValue = "${variable.name.in.app.properties}"`?

Comment: Never tried that way. Thank you though @Bohemian

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that but it gives me some error that forces the variable to be final. I can test out the direct method.

Comment: No! `defaultValue = myDefaultValue` doesn't work because defaultValue expects a final. @Bohemian `defaultValue = "${variable.name.in.app.properties}"` is the correct solution.

Comment: @donnadulcinea what exactly do you mean by "defaultValue expects a final"?

Comment: The defaultValue parameter must be final (you must assign a constant value that can't be changed). So the solution defaultValue = myDefaultValue is not acceptable if myDefaultValue is defined as above, as an injected string value, Spring will raise a error. Your solution (@Bohemian) is the only correct one.