# spring.data.rest.max-page-size does not seem to be working

Tags: spring-data-rest

Under Spring Boot **1.3.0.M5** I'm using

```
spring.data.rest.max-page-size=10
```

in **application.properties**.

But I still can set the size to 40 in a URL and get a correct response.
For example :
http://localhost:8080/cine20-spring/api/films?page=0&size=40&sort=title,asc

will give me back 40 films

So what is the use of this parameter ?

**Update test with Spring-Boot 1.4.2**

There is still a problem :
By default WITHOUT the dependencies  **spring-boot-starter-data-rest**
, the max-page-size is set to **2000** by default
and changing the max-page-size value won't work :

```
spring.data.rest.max-page-size=0x7fffffff
```

Adding **spring-boot-starter-data-rest**
=> the max-page-size is now set to **1000** by default
, then changing the param max-page-size will work:

```
spring.data.rest.max-page-size=0x7fffffff
```

I still believe, this is strange behavior.

In : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/RepositoryRestConfiguration.java

You could find `private int maxPageSize = 1000;` which explains why it changed to 1000. I haven't found, why it is set to 2000 from the start though.

I would like to set the param `spring.data.rest.max-page-size` freely without the need to add the dependency : **spring-boot-starter-data-rest**, but unfortunately I haven't found a way so far.

Answer (score 20):

This was somewhat of a **gotcha** for me. I think the easiest solution is using configuration properties instead of code. So this is what I found and what worked for me.

If you are using a `Pageable` in a `@RestController` then you can set it using property `spring.data.web.pageable.max-page-size`.

If you are using a `Pageable` in a `@RepositoryRestResource` then you can set it using property `spring.data.rest.max-page-size`.

Answer (score 3):

I am able to do this on Spring Boot 2.1.x and 2.3.3 to override the default Pageable max page size of 2000.

```java
@Configuration
public class PageableConfig {

    @Bean
    PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer pageableResolverCustomizer() {
        return pageableResolver -> pageableResolver.setMaxPageSize(9999);
    }
}
```

Adding either of these `spring.data.web.pageable.max-page-size` (`spring.data.web.pageable.maxPageSize`)
or `spring.data.rest.max-page-size` (`spring.data.rest.maxPageSize`) properties in `application.properties` did not work for me. i.e.

```
# these properties did not allow me to override the default of 2000 for maxPageSize
spring.data.web.pageable.max-page-size=9999
spring.data.rest.max-page-size=9999
```

For further details, kindly visit https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14413 and this https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1290

See related SO: Set default page size for JPA Pageable Object post:
[Set default page size for JPA Pageable Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27032433/set-default-page-size-for-jpa-pageable-object)

Comment: I can confirm that this works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me only with config enforced through code:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomizedRestMvcConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration
{
  @Override
  public RepositoryRestConfiguration config() {
    RepositoryRestConfiguration config = super.config();
    config.setMaxPageSize(10000);
    return config;
  }
}
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#_changing_the_base_uri

Answer (score 0):

Try this will work
in properties add this line

```
spring.data.rest.default-page-size=1000
```