# Spring Data Rest - Set request timeout

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have a `Visit` entity which refers to a `Patient` entity by `ManyToOne` relationship. The repository for `Visit` is:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "visits", path = "visits", excerptProjection=VisitProjection.class)
public interface VisitRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Visit, Long> {

    @RestResource(path="all")
    List<Visit> findByPatientIdContaining(@Param("keyword") String keyword);

}
```

When searching visits by patient ID with `/visits/search/all?keyword=1` which may return millions of records, the query is forever pending and never ends. In the console there are dozens of hibernate sqls printed every second. **How can I set the request timeout from server side?**

I have tried:

1. And `Transactional` annotation with timeout attribute to repository method: (works a little but still takes long to timeout)

> ```
> @RestResource(path="all")
> @Transactional(timeout=2)
> List<Visit> findByPatientIdContaining(@Param("keyword") String keyword);
> ```

2. add some timeout properties to `application.properties`: (just doesn't work at all):

> ```
> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.timeout=2
> spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.query.timeout=2
> spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=2
> server.connection-timeout=2
> rest.connection.connection-request-timeout=2
> rest.connection.connect-timeout=2
> rest.connection.read-timeout=2
> server.servlet.session.timeout=2
> spring.session.timeout=2
> spring.jdbc.template.query-timeout=2
> spring.transaction.default-timeout=2
> spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.query.timeout=2
> javax.persistence.query.timeout=2
> server.tomcat.connection-timeout=5
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, no one using your API is going to want millions of records in one hit so use the provided paging functionality to make the result set more manageable:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#paging-and-sorting

```
@RestResource(path="all")
Page<Visit> findByPatientIdContaining(@Param("keyword") String keyword, Pageable p);
```

Clients can specify the records they want the records returned by adding the params:

`?page=1&size=5`

Comment: I know pagination is a solution, but what if some client sets `size=10000` accidentally? Still looking for some way to set a request timeout.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675349/spring-data-rest-max-page-size-does-not-seem-to-work