# Spring Boot v2.2.2.RELEASE throw error when Pagination Size more than anticipated

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I'm using ***Spring Boot (v2.2.2.RELEASE) + Spring Data Mongo + Spring REST + Spring HATEOAS*** example. In this example, if consumer sends Pagination max-page-size=200 more than 200 then I would need to show the error message saying maximum allowable size is 200.

I went through numerous links like: [spring.data.rest.max-page-size does not seem to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675349/spring-data-rest-max-page-size-does-not-seem-to-work), but none of the solution is working for me yet.

I am using HATEOAS implementation and using PagedResourcesAssembler and RepresentationModelAssemblerSupport.

Any pointers?

```
@Configuration
public class RespositoryConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {
    @Value("${paging.default.pageSize}")
    private int size;

    @Value("${paging.default.page}")
    private int page;

    public RespositoryConfiguration(ApplicationContext context, ObjectFactory<ConversionService> conversionService) {
        super(context, conversionService);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableResolver() {
        HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = super.pageableResolver();
        resolver.setPageParameterName("page");
        resolver.setSizeParameterName("size");
        resolver.setOneIndexedParameters(false);
        resolver.setFallbackPageable(PageRequest.of(0, 25));
        resolver.setMaxPageSize(200);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Note: I also used `spring.data.web.pageable.max-page-size=200` in `application.properties` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue with the below code and this works very fine.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    ...
    ....

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
        PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver() {

            @Override
            public Pageable resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter,
                    @Nullable ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest,
                    @Nullable WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) {
                Pageable p = super.resolveArgument(methodParameter, mavContainer, webRequest, binderFactory);

                if(p.getPageSize() > Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("max.pagination.size"))) {
                    throw new MandatoryResourceException(env.getProperty("max.pagination.size.error.message"),
                            env.getProperty("max.pagination.size.error.code"));
                }

                return p;
            }
        };

        resolvers.add(resolver);
        WebMvcConfigurer.super.addArgumentResolvers(resolvers);
    }
}
```