# Setting default-page-size for Spring Pageable not taking effect

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Most of my research finds setting the defaults of Pageable per endpoint but I wish to set an application-wide default to unlimited, meaning if no limit/sort parameters are passed to return all available resources.

Given endpoint code:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> get(Pageable pageable) {
    ...
}
```

**Question 1:** Why doesn't this take effect? `application.yml`

```
spring:
  profiles: local

  data:
      rest:
        default-page-size: 99
```

Local profile is being used and other settings within are taking effect.
Requests coming in with no Pageable parameters still receive the default of 20 instead of the override of 99

**Question 2:** Is it possible to set to unlimited from here?

In other answers of defaulting these settings via per-endpoint annotation (`@PageableDefault`), they used `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to which I assume wont work in the YAML once I have that working :)

Comment: Have you tried debugging if property is loaded from file using spring boot actuator with  {management-context}/env/spring.data.rest.default-page-size request ?

Comment: @dev-null - Yes, it shows the property being set: `{
  "spring.data.rest.default-page-size" : "99"
}`. It does however show it as a string, would that be concerning?  
Looked at others that are working and they show up as string too though: `{
  "spring.threadPoolConfig.corePoolSize" : "5"
}`

Comment: Properties are just string so it should be ok. What version of spring boot do you use ? Can you post your `pom.xml` here ?

Comment: I think the problem you're having is the config you're looking at is for REST based on data Repositories, not controllers. This documentation would seem to suggest that. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#_changing_other_spring_data_rest_properties 

The only way I can get it to work is through code as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27032433/set-default-page-size-for-jpa-pageable-object