# How to change Spring Data Page number default 0 or change ng-table default

Tags: angularjs, spring-data, ngtable

i use Spring MVC and Spring Data to get data,in  front end i use angular js ng-table to display.but the ng-table send the page Number default is 1  start then spring Data pageAble is default 0 start.

i know that is ok but when you click page size button it change to page 1(to default)

```
new ngTableParams({
    page: 0,            // show first page
    count: 10           // count per page
}, {});
```

so how can fix them?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27034846/1356423

Comment: thank you Alan Hay，i see that. it work .but it not all pageAble set default 1 page start,just for Controller useful.