# Offset calculation in Spring Pagination

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a service with pagination index starting from 1.I get the list of entity after some logic I return the same(responses) as below

```
totalCount = responses.size();
return new PageImpl<>(responses, pageable, totalCount);
```

and **when I have requested the 1st page** as

```
new PageRequest(1, 100)
```

I get back the response as

```
{"content": [
       {
            "id": "e1",
        }{
            "id": "2",
        }
     ],
    "last": false,
    "totalElements": 102,
    "totalPages": 2,
    "size": 100,
    "number": 1,
    "sort": null,
    "first": true,
    "numberOfElements": 2
}
```

Here    even though I have  **"numberOfElements": 2** I get back  **"totalElements": 102**

The issue which I found is because of  pageable.getOffset() calculation  in PageImpl

```
this.total = !content.isEmpty() && pageable != null && pageable.getOffset() 
+ pageable.getPageSize() > total
                ? pageable.getOffset() + content.size() : total;
```

In my scenario for the 1st Page I'am getting offset as 100 (1*100). How do I resolve this.

**Note** : *I use a third party service to get the responses which is indexed 1 . So I am trying to align my service to that so that the entire logic follow the same indexing.*

Comment: If it is of any use, you can configure Spring Data to use 1 rather than 0 for the first page as outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27032433/set-default-page-size-for-jpa-pageable-object/27034846#27034846

Answer (score 2):

The result you get is correct, since `PageRequest` used zero-based pages as stated in the [API docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html):

> **Parameters**:
>
> page - zero-based page index.
>
> size - the size of the page to be returned.

So that means you're retrieving the second page (not the first one), and since you have a limit of 100 records and a total of 102 records, you'll only retrieve the last two of them.

You can still expose a 1-based number though:

```
new PageRequest(page-1, 100);
```

---

Alternatively, you can customize this by implementing `Pageable`. This allows you to override the actual offset being used by Spring data.

Nonetheless, this doesn't change the fact that Spring data expects `getPageNumber()` to be a zero based number. You **cannot** change that, you can only add an abstraction layer on top of it to make it meet your requirements.

Comment: You can (or at least could in the past) configure 0/1 for the first page https://stackoverflow.com/a/27034846/1356423. The default was actually 1 in early versions of the Spring Data library.

Answer (score 1):

And what's wrong with that? `totalElements` tells you how many elements are stored within the data source. `numberOfElements` tells you how many elements the current page contains.
When have 102 elements in total and you requesting page 2 with size 100, you should get exactly the response you received.

**What probably confuses you:**

With `new PageRequest(1, 100)` you are requesting the **2nd** page as the index starts at 0.

Comment: Yes.So I want PageRequest to be aligned with the service as when I give Page request  new PageRequest(1, 100)  It should treat it as 1st page.Is there any way for the same other than implementing a Custom PageImpl and overriding the offset logic.

Comment: No. That is something you do not change! If you want to get page one you have to do `new PageRequest(0, 100)`. What would be the benefit of it anyway? In Java (actually in most every language) indexes are 0-based.

Comment: If I do that the total elements would be correct but the Page number would be 0 and user have requested for Page number 1. I have this scenario because for getting the responses I use a third party service which is indexed 1.

Comment: This is an index. The first index always starts at 0. Starting an index at 1 will generally end in problems. Read this article for a scientific reasoning: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html

Comment: Look at it this way: in `new PageRequest(0, 100)` the `0` means the offset from the possible page list. Means you will skip 0 pages, leading to the first page. Having `new PageRequest(1, 100)`  means you want to skip 1 page and therefor get page 2.

Comment: @Rajgopal what do you mean with "the user requested"? This number is a technical detail, if you don't want to expose it, you just do minus one in your service and pass that value to the `Page`.

Comment: @g00glen00b I have this scenario because for getting the responses I use a third party service which is indexed 1 . So I am trying to align my service to that so that the entire logic follow the same indexing.

Comment: @Rajgopal Your service can perfectly use a 1-based index, you'll just have to subtract 1 from it when you use Spring data.