# Pageable - PageRequest, no spring boot properties for the page, only available for the default-page-size

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, pageable

I already followed the link: [Set default page size for JPA Pageable Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27032433/set-default-page-size-for-jpa-pageable-object), but I only see option to set the `page-size` like `spring.data.web.pageable.default-page-size`, but I don't see option to `page` to any customizable value. I know page should start from 0 only, what if I want to override it to other value?

[image]

Also, what is the difference between 
`spring.data.rest.default-page-size` and `spring.data.web.pageable.default-page-size` when to use what option is not clear?

Comment: I don't understand your question? You want to start by default from a page other than 0?

Comment: @Simon Martinelli - Yes, I would like start it from Page-1, I dont want to show first 9 records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to set the default start page. This is always 0.

If you use Spring Data REST Repositories https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-rest you must use `spring.data.rest.default-page-size` in all other cases `spring.data.web.pageable.default-page-size`