# Unable to override defaults of Pagination in Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, pageable

I am working on Spring Boot Spring Data Mongo Pageable example. I want to set pagination value default `page=1` and `size=5`, if no one provided any values.

Now when user provided any values, I want Pageable object to use those values and not default one.

Crated Bug: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2313

Its not working in my case. I'm **not** using Spring `HATEOAS` in my application.

```
@GetMapping()
public ResponseEntity<Page<Student>> getAllstudents(Pageable pageable){
    return studentService.findAllstudents(pageable);
}
```

in `application.yml` file

```
# Mongo DB details
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: TEST
      host: localhost
      port: 27017

    web:
      pageable:
        default-page-size: 2
        size-parameter: 0
        one-indexed-parameters: true
        page-parameter: page
```

Or I want exactly like below using Spring boot

```
<mvc:argument-resolvers>
            <bean class="org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver" >
                <property name="oneIndexedParameters" value="true"></property>
                <property name="pageParameterName" value="page"></property>
                <property name="sizeParameterName" value="size"></property>
                <property name="fallbackPageable">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest">
                        <constructor-arg name="page" value="1" />
                        <constructor-arg name="size" value="${paging.default.pageSize}" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
```

Swagger UI:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing reports that those `pageable` settings in application.yml only work with Spring HATEOAS. I would try using the `@PageableDefault` annotation instead.

Comment: Can we configure this as global level ? I dont see its possible